# expo build - building an managed expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo app that is fully functional on the simulator, 3 weeks ago when i was building an app with `expo build:ios` everything was working. On the 4th of jan, expo made an update that this will no longer work.

Now, i am trying to build my managed app with `npx eas build --platform ios`, in the console everything works then i get the build details.

When i open the link, mu build fails in install pods and here is my error message

```
Using Expo modules
Auto-generating `.xcode.env.local` with $NODE_BINARY=/Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin/node
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `APP`: BVLinearGradient, RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNGestureHandler, RNImageColors, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, lottie-react-native, react-native-contacts, react-native-maps, react-native-netinfo, and react-native-webview
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "EXFirebaseCore":
  In Podfile:
    EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`)
Specs satisfying the `EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
Error: Some pods require a higher minimum deployment target.
You can use the expo-build-properties config plugin (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/) to override the default native build properties and set a different minimum deployment target.
```

I went into node modules on my app and deleted `expo-firebase-core` folder and still the same error occurs when i try to build again.

Can someone please clarify:

1. the difference between expo build and eas build
2. why is the build installing pods when its a managed workflow

UPDATE

I also have `expo-firebase-recaptcha` installed which uses `"expo-firebase-core": "~6.0.0"`

Is that causing the error?